# currentUser is null after refreshing page

Tags: angular, browser

I have a login component , a service and a storage helper.
The login method works fine until I refresh HomePage (here I need user's data) because I'm injecting an empty service.
So, to solve this, in app.component I've created a method that sets the currentUser using the token saved it to localStorage.

My problem is that the currentUser is null after refreshing the page and I think it is because of the token not being saved.

How to solve this?

app.component.ts

```
 getUserDetails() {
    this.accountService.getUserDetails().subscribe(res => {
      this.userService.setCurrentUser(<User>res);
    }, error => {
      StorageHelper.killSession();
    });
  }
```

login.service.ts

```
  login(credentials) {
    delete credentials.rememberMe;
    return this.apiService.post(`${this.resourceUrl}/login`, credentials);
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
login() {
    this.accountService.login(this.authForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      StorageHelper.saveToken((<User>res).token);
      this.userService.setCurrentUser((<User>res));
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.getReturnUrl());
    }, error => {
    });
 }
```

storagehelper.ts

```
private static readonly tokenKey: string = "VendorJwtToken";
private static readonly customerTypeKey: string = 'VN_CT';

public static getToken() {
    return window.localStorage[this.tokenKey];
}

public static saveToken(token: String) {
    window.localStorage[this.tokenKey] = token;
}
```

Comment: Try with setItem localStorage.setItem('user', token); and also do console.log before reloading in the inspect to check whether key is set properly or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The logged in user details are stored in local storage so the user
>   will stay logged in if they refresh the browser and also between
>   browser sessions until they logout. If you don't want the user to stay
>   logged in between refreshes or sessions the behaviour could easily be
>   changed by storing user details somewhere less persistent such as
>   session storage or in a property of the authentication service.

You should save it in `localStorage` like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username: username, password: password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

you can have a look at this link for step by step setup : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial