# How to handle internationalization and user session in Angular?

Tags: angular, session, internationalization, jwt

So i have an Angular app and i'm using json web token for security. For each language there is an own version of the app because of Angular's internationalization process. The user requests the app and gets it in a default language. After login in a json web token (jwt) is send back to the client and stored in the local storage. From now on the jwt is send with every web api request through http interceptor. 
So far, so good. Lets say the user changes the language. I need to send the chosen language to the web api and store it in user settings (which i'm already doing) and redirect the user to requested app version. Here comes the problem. If i redirect the user to other language version of the app, the browser refreshes and my jwt session is lost. Now the user needs to login. Did i miss something?

Comment: So, you have two apps on different domains?

Comment: Same domain but different routes. I'm doing a redirect on IIS. I have a default english version myapp.com and lets say a german version myapp.com/de.

Comment: Perhaps this could be useful. I did not read it entirely, but the basic idea is to use an iframe on another domain and communicate from your Angular apps with that iframe. There are more ways to do this, but this is one: [Learning from XAuth: Cross-domain localStorage](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/)

Comment: basically The logged in user details are stored in local storage so the user will stay logged in if they refresh the browser and also between browser sessions until they logout ... I think this link should solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952995/currentuser-is-null-after-refreshing-page/58953137#58953137

Comment: If it is the same domain, the localstorage should persist. Is your problem session-related? In other words, are you also keeping track of things within a session? Perhaps you have a double auth. Both a jwt header and a session cookie.

Comment: Ok, if i go with local storage and save the token on the client, how do i authenticate a user when i land on the login page after changing the language? I mean, when i login in, i send username and password to get the token. But if i already have the token, the login mechanism should be different.